# Evaluation in a Spacy NER model

Tags: python, spacy

I am trying to evaluate a trained NER Model created using [spacy lib](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/training-ner).
 Normally for these kind of problems you can use f1 score (a ratio between precision and recall). I could not find in the documentation an accuracy function for a trained NER model.

I am not sure if it's correct but I am trying to do it with the following way(example) and using `f1_score` from `sklearn`:

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
import spacy
from spacy.gold import GoldParse


nlp = spacy.load("en") #load NER model
test_text = "my name is John" # text to test accuracy
doc_to_test = nlp(test_text) # transform the text to spacy doc format

# we create a golden doc where we know the tagged entity for the text to be tested
doc_gold_text= nlp.make_doc(test_text)
entity_offsets_of_gold_text = [(11, 15,"PERSON")]
gold = GoldParse(doc_gold_text, entities=entity_offsets_of_gold_text)

# bring the data in a format acceptable for sklearn f1 function
y_true = ["PERSON" if "PERSON" in x else 'O' for x in gold.ner]
y_predicted = [x.ent_type_ if x.ent_type_ !='' else 'O' for x in doc_to_test]
f1_score(y_true, y_predicted, average='macro')`[1]
> 1.0
```

Any thoughts are or insights are useful.

Comment: https://dulaj.medium.com/confusion-matrix-visualization-for-spacy-ner-9e9d99120ee9  : check this link, good article to read for spacy evaluation.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can find different metrics including F-score, recall and precision in [spaCy/scorer.py](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/scorer.py).

This example shows how you can use it:

```
import spacy
from spacy.gold import GoldParse
from spacy.scorer import Scorer

def evaluate(ner_model, examples):
    scorer = Scorer()
    for input_, annot in examples:
        doc_gold_text = ner_model.make_doc(input_)
        gold = GoldParse(doc_gold_text, entities=annot)
        pred_value = ner_model(input_)
        scorer.score(pred_value, gold)
    return scorer.scores

# example run

examples = [
    ('Who is Shaka Khan?',
     [(7, 17, 'PERSON')]),
    ('I like London and Berlin.',
     [(7, 13, 'LOC'), (18, 24, 'LOC')])
]

ner_model = spacy.load(ner_model_path) # for spaCy's pretrained use 'en_core_web_sm'
results = evaluate(ner_model, examples)
```

The `scorer.scores` returns multiple scores. When running the example, the result looks like this: (Note the low scores occuring because the examples classify London and Berlin as 'LOC' while the model classifies them as 'GPE'. You can figure this out by looking at the `ents_per_type`.)

```
{'uas': 0.0, 'las': 0.0, 'las_per_type': {'attr': {'p': 0.0, 'r': 0.0, 'f': 0.0}, 'root': {'p': 0.0, 'r': 0.0, 'f': 0.0}, 'compound': {'p': 0.0, 'r': 0.0, 'f': 0.0}, 'nsubj': {'p': 0.0, 'r': 0.0, 'f': 0.0}, 'dobj': {'p': 0.0, 'r': 0.0, 'f': 0.0}, 'cc': {'p': 0.0, 'r': 0.0, 'f': 0.0}, 'conj': {'p': 0.0, 'r': 0.0, 'f': 0.0}}, 'ents_p': 33.33333333333333, 'ents_r': 33.33333333333333, 'ents_f': 33.33333333333333, 'ents_per_type': {'PERSON': {'p': 100.0, 'r': 100.0, 'f': 100.0}, 'LOC': {'p': 0.0, 'r': 0.0, 'f': 0.0}, 'GPE': {'p': 0.0, 'r': 0.0, 'f': 0.0}}, 'tags_acc': 0.0, 'token_acc': 100.0, 'textcat_score': 0.0, 'textcats_per_cat': {}}
```

The example is taken from a [spaCy example on github](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/training/train_ner_standalone.py#L159) (link does not work anymore). It was last tested with spacy 2.2.4.

Comment: 1. you're github link is broken
2. What is self in this context? Where may I find self.make_gold?

Comment: @farlee2121 I have updated the answer to be more clear.

Comment: Can you confirm that this is still working (for v2)? I get a KeyError at
`gold = GoldParse(doc_gold_text, entities=annot)`

Comment: I get an error at this point as well. `gold = GoldParse(doc_gold_text, entities=_) File "gold.pyx", line 418, in spacy.gold.GoldParse.__init__ KeyError: 0`

Comment: I looked on the site and it looks like this has changed with the new version. https://spacy.io/usage/v2 . I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Remember to import the scorer class `from spacy.scorer import Scorer `

Comment: @EvanLalo make sure that `annot` is an iterable tuples, not a dictionary. I ran into the same issue.

Comment: Try this `entities=annot['entities']` instead of the default `entities=annot`.

Comment: How do you compute PRF metrics for each category ('PERSON', 'GPE', 'LOC", etc) separately?

Comment: @ArnoldKlein In spacy v2.1.5, it now supports PRF per entity type. https://spacy.io/api/scorer

Comment: for spacy  v3: Execute the evaluate command on cli as mentioned in https://spacy.io/api/cli#evaluate

Answer (score 6):

since i faced the same problem, i am going to post here the code for the example showed in the accepted answer, but for spacy V3:

```
import spacy
from spacy.scorer import Scorer
from spacy.tokens import Doc
from spacy.training.example import Example

examples = [
    ('Who is Shaka Khan?',
     {(7, 17, 'PERSON')}),
    ('I like London and Berlin.',
     {(7, 13, 'LOC'), (18, 24, 'LOC')})
]

def evaluate(ner_model, examples):
    scorer = Scorer()
    example = []
    for input_, annot in examples:
        pred = ner_model(input_)
        print(pred,annot)
        temp = Example.from_dict(pred, dict.fromkeys(annot))
        example.append(temp)
    scores = scorer.score(example)
    return scores

ner_model = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') # for spaCy's pretrained use 'en_core_web_sm'
results = evaluate(ner_model, examples)
print(results)
```

Breaking changes ocurred because libraries such as goldParse deprecated

I believe the part of the answer about metrics is still valid

Answer (score 2):

Note that in spaCy v3 there is an [`evaluate` command](https://spacy.io/api/cli#evaluate) you can use easily from the command line instead of writing custom code to handle things.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I used to calculate accuracy for my Spacy's Custom NER model

```
def flat_accuracy(text, annotations):
    actual_ents = [ents[2] for ents in annotations]
    prediction = nlp_ner(text)
    pred_ents = [ent.text for ent in prediction.ents]
    return 1 if actual_ents == pred_ents else 0


predict_points = sum(flat_accuracy(test_text[0], test_text[1]) for test_text in examples)
output = (predict_points/len(examples)) * 100
output --> 82%
```

Answer (score 1):

I searched for many solutions on the internet but failed to find any working solution. Now that I was able to figure out the root of the problem, I am sharing my code, similar to the original question. I hope someone can still find it useful. It works with SpaCy V3.3.

```
from spacy.scorer import Scorer
from spacy.training import Example

def evaluate(ner_model, samples):
    scorer = Scorer(ner_model)
    example = []
    for sample in samples:
        pred = ner_model(sample['text'])
        print(pred, sample['entities'])
        temp_ex = Example.from_dict(pred, {'entities': sample['entities']})
        example.append(temp_ex)
    scores = scorer.score(example)
    
    return scores
```

**Note:** *samples* should be a valid spacy v3 formatted JSON data like below:

```
{'text': '#Causes - Quinsy - CA0K.1\nPeri Tonsillar Abscess is usually a complication of an untreated or partially treated acute tonsillitis. The infection, in these cases, spreads to the peritonsillar area (peritonsillitis). This region comprises loose connective tissue and is hence susceptible to formation of abscess.', 'entities': [(10, 16, 'Disease_E'), (26, 48, 'Disease_E'), (112, 129, 'Complication_E'), (177, 213, 'Anatomy_E'), (237, 260, 'Anatomy_E'), (302, 309, 'Disease_E')]}
```