# How can I get the confusion matrix used to calculate the metrics for NER models?

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

Similar to this previous question [How to calculate the overall accuracy of custom trained spacy ner model with confusion matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56252016/how-to-calculate-the-overall-accuracy-of-custom-trained-spacy-ner-model-with-con)

spaCy provides Precision, Recall, F1 scores in the `meta.json` file when it writes out the trained NER model.  Also these values are available when running the evaluation command `python -m spacy evaluate`.  However is it possible to get the counts for TP, FP, FN used to calculate these values?

Furthermore is it possible to output the actual text / tokens which resulted in a False Positive or False Negative?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get the counts for TP, FP, FN when evaluating all entity types using

```
scorer = nlp.evaluate(testset)
TP = scorer.ner.tp
FP = scorer.ner.fp
FN = scorer.ner.fn
```

and when evaluating per entity type using

```
scorer = nlp.evaluate(testset)
for ent_type, scorer_ent_type in scorer.ner_per_ents.items():
    TP = scorer_ent_type.tp
    FP = scorer_ent_type.fp
    FN = scorer_ent_type.fn
    print('Ent_type:', ent_type, 'TP:', TP, 'FP:', FP, 'FN:', FN)
```

When training and evaluating your spacy NER model, as I understand, the scores for all entities are calculated in [this line](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/61b07eb4b32cb01912cd671d65ef886e582a5c9e/spacy/scorer.py#L305) in the spacy code. The scores per entity are calculated in [this line](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/61b07eb4b32cb01912cd671d65ef886e582a5c9e/spacy/scorer.py#L303). In both cases, the [score_set](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/61b07eb4b32cb01912cd671d65ef886e582a5c9e/spacy/scorer.py#L20) function is called. It updates the TP, FP, and FN in the scorer. If you set breakpoints at those lines and debug, you can look into the variables `doc`, `cand_ents`, and `gold_ents`, and have a look at the FP and FN with

```
print(doc)
print(cand_ents-gold_ents) #FP
print(gold_ents-cand_ents) #FN
```

Late answer but I hope it helps.

Comment: Why the counts for TN is not available in above solution ? Can I calculate it this way `TN = total number of samples - (TP + FP + FN)` ?

Comment: @MurariMahaseth Yes, you can calculate TN like that.