# How do I evaluate a custom pipeline component with a custom attribute?

Tags: spacy

### Questions:

1. How can I give [GoldParse](https://spacy.io/api/goldparse#init) the gold data for a custom attribute?
2. How can I extend the [properties of Scorer](https://spacy.io/api/scorer#properties) by custom scores which are based on a custom attribute?

### Explanation

I have implemented a custom pipeline component setting a custom attribute which was set with `Doc.set_extension('results', default=[])`. I want to evaluate my pipeline with labelled data (something like `{text: "This is some text", results: ["banana", "picture"]}`). It seems to me that [GoldParse](https://spacy.io/api/goldparse) and [Scorer](https://spacy.io/api/scorer) are doing what I need with default attributes, but I can't find information on how to use them with a custom attribute.

I have seen and understood examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44841535), but they only ever deal with default attributes.

### What I've tried

- I have tried figuring out whether I can somehow configure the two classes for custom attributes/scores, but haven't found a way. The parameters of the init method of GoldParse and the Scorer properties seem to be fixed.
- I have thought about extending the two classes with subclasses, but they don't seem easily extendable to me.

### What I would like to avoid

Of course I can copy the code from Scorer and GoldParse which I need and add code for my custom attribute, but that seems like a bad solution. Also, considering how spaCy encourages you to extend a pipeline and a Doc, I would be surprised if the evaluation of those extensions were this hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it actually is this hard in spacy v2. It's very hard to add things to `GoldParse` (basically a don't-try-this-at-home level of hard) and the `Scorer` is also hard to extend.

We're working on this for the upcoming spacy v3, where the scoring methods will be implemented more generally and each component will be able to provide its own `score` method. Be aware that this is still unstable, but if you're curious you can have a look at: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/pull/5731. `GoldParse` has been replaced with `Example`, which stores both the gold annotation and the predicted annotation on individual `Doc` objects, getting rid of the restrictions related to `GoldParse`.

If you have a doc-level extension (as above) then you should probably just use a different library for evaluation. You could potentially use `ROCAUCScore` or `PRFScore` from `spacy.scorer`, but it may be easier to use something like `sklearn` metrics instead. (The `ROCAUCScore` is just a simplified version of the `sklearn` ROC AUC metric.)

If you have a token-level extension, for v2 I think the best you can do within spacy is to use `PRFScore` and extract the alignment bits based on words from a `GoldParse` to use outside of the scorer itself. Something like this:

```py
import spacy
from spacy.scorer import PRFScore

nlp = spacy.load("my_model")
score = PRFScore()
for text, gold_words, gold_attrs in zip(texts, gold_words_list, gold_attrs_list):
    # NOTE: gold_attrs must be aligned with gold_words
    # gold_words = ["a", "b", "c", ...]
    # gold_attrs = ["a1", "b1", "c1", ...]

    gold = GoldParse(nlp.make_doc(text), words=gold_words)
    doc = nlp(text)

    gold_values = set()
    cand_values = set()
    for i, gold_attr in enumerate(gold_attrs):
        gold_values.add((i, gold_attr))
    for token in doc:
        if token.orth_.isspace():
            continue
        gold_i = gold.cand_to_gold[token.i]
        if gold_i is not None:
            cand_values.add((gold_i, doc._.attr))
    score.score_set(cand_values, gold_values)

print(score.fscore)
```

This is an untested sketch that should parallel how `token.tag` is evaluated in the `Scorer`. The alignment bits are the trickiest part, so if you don't have misalignments between gold words and spacy's tokenization, then you may also be better off exporting your results and using a different library for evaluation.

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen to know a release schedule for v3? I can't seem to find one.

Comment: There's no set release schedule, sorry!